# Why does SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE [timestamp_field]<"NOW()" work in MySQL but not in Mariadb?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am transitioning an application that I'm writing from the latest version of MySQL to the latest version of Mariadb (10.1.something), and so far everything has been smooth, EXCEPT for the following:

```
SELECT `fields` FROM `my_table` WHERE `timestamp_created`<"NOW()"
```

works in MySQL, but not in MariaDB. The `timestamp_created` field of course has timestamp data. Something like

```
SELECT `fields` FROM `my_table` WHERE `timestamp_created`<"2016-02-19 19:59:59"
```

works in MariaDB, but it doesn't work when I use `timestamp_created`<"NOW()"

Why? NOW() basically works the same way in MySQL as it does in MariaDB, so why is it that using NOW() to compare timestamps doesn't work in MariaDB?

Thanks!

Comment: "NOW()" is a String not a TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2):

`NOW()` is a function, not a string.

```
SELECT
    fields
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    timestamp_created < NOW()
```

On MySQL, double-quotes `"` are used as escaped identifier delimiters in much the same way that T-SQL/MSSQL uses the square-bracket characters `[`, `]`. MySQL strings must be delimited with single-quote characters `'`, so your use of `"NOW()"` is interpreted the same way as `NOW()` or `[NOW()]` would be.

This behaviour is documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html

> ...string literals can be quoted only within single quotation marks because a string quoted within double quotation marks is interpreted as an identifier.

Comment: @RickJames I have amended my answer to explain.